# Creating a HTTP request to return Json data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am creating an asp.net c# website that basically allows people to select a PC component and then I want to do a web search and find the cheapest price. I am using Google Shopping API and know how to create the URL to search for the specific product and display the json data.

I would like some advice as to how I can write the HTTP request, return the json data file and convert it to be displayed on a webpage. Ideally i want to do this in the code behind for a button click. I am new to all of this so any help is really appreciated.

All i have so far is:

> ```
>        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key={KEY}&country=UK&q=BX80637153570K&rankBy=price:ascending&maxResults=1&alt=json");
>         HttpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
> ```

and can't work out what to do next

Answer (score 2):

I have something like this in one of my projects:

```
public string HttpGet(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    try {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    } finally {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Then I can just do:

```
string json = HttpGet("http://www.example.com/");
```

I'm brushing over things like checking the content type etc for `application/json` and just reading the contents. You might want to do that.

Once you have the JSON string you can use Json.NET or .NET's internal deserializer to turn it into something useful. I prefer Json.NET, for example:

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

You can then do with `obj` whatever you wish.

Comment: You can check some detail here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211489/Using-JSON-with-ASP-NET-3-5

Comment: @Lloyd. Thanks for the answer. I have tried to implement the code you gave me. I have written the first part in the code behind page but I don't understand where to go from there. Eventually I want to be able to run the request on a Button_Click and display the resulting data on the web page. Could you please give me some idea how to implement the rest of the code? I am struggling to find any relevant help with regards to the Google shopping API.